# "Class javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane cannot be cast to class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader"

Tags: java, exception, javafx, scenebuilder

I was using JavaFX to create a login form. After login, the username you wrote will be displayed on the screen as "Welcome, username". But, when I clicked on the login button, there was an error with the message:

```
class javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane cannot be cast to class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader (javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane is in module javafx.graphics of loader 'app'; javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader is in module javafx.fxml of loader 'app')
```

Here's my code:

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    private static Stage stg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            stg = stage;
            stage.setResizable(false);
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
            stage.setTitle("Login");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 340));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void changeSceneWelcome(String fxml, String username) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
            AfterLoginController afterLoginController = loader.getController();
            afterLoginController.welcomeName(username);
            Parent pane = loader.load();
            stg.setResizable(false);
            stg.setTitle("Welcome!");
            stg.setScene(new Scene(pane, 800, 600));
            stg.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error happenned at the `changeSceneWelcome` method.

What should I do to fix this bug? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Complete stacktrace please. And complete fxml file please. And the code which is calling changeSceneWelcome() please.

Comment: In your start method, you have `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load`, which is correct.  In your changeSceneWelcome method, you have `FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load` which is the source of your problem.  FXMLLoader.load did not return a loader in the first call, so I’m not sure why you thought it would do so in the second call.  Perhaps you should just use `new FXMLLoader` instead of the static `load` method?

Comment: May I introduce you to the JavaFX library "SimpleJavaFxApplicationBase"? Maybe the "SceneAPI" is something for you. You can Switch scenes easily and Pass values to the new scene. https://wedasoft.com/projects/simple-java-fx-application-base/